# Marker size on Excel charts to scale

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I often use charts to make graphical representations of the inputs in my engineering spreadsheets. I often have bolt holes and other round objects in them and, as such, need to draw circles accurately. I have, in the past, done it so that I generate the points of a circle using the circle formula then plot those, but this is very heavy-handed when I have many circles in the chart and when the number of circles needs to be dynamic etc. The other method I have used is to plit the centre points and use circular data markers and then change the size of them dynamically with VBA code when the input changes - however, the marker size is measured in points and is not to scale in the chart meaning they often don't look right.

Can anyone help me with a method to make the marker sizes to scale in my charts? VBA code is fine, and I think necessary, for this task.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Draw a circle (ellipse) of the size you need outside of the chart somewhere.

Plot the X and Y for the center of the circle in the chart.

Copy the circle, select the point, and paste (ctrl+V), and the circle will replace the marker.

Comment: Hi Jon. That's a decent solution in some cases, but for me it doesn't work since it's not dynamic (in terms of marker size), and it's almost impossible to draw the circle to the exact scale by hand and, even if you could, it would become wrong if you resized the chart. Thanks for your input, however.

Comment: Well, if you're using VBA anyway, you can draw the circles as exactly as required, then paste them in.